# Swift Constants are more powerful than constants in C

Tags: c, swift

I read the following statement in Swift 4 Programming language book by Apple.“**Swift also makes extensive use of variables whose values can’t be changed. These are known as constants, and are much more powerful than constants in C**”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4).” iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/in/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4-0-3/id881256329?mt=11

Can someone explain how it is more powerful than C constants ? what is that so special about Swift constants? Question might be trivial one. But i am not to able to find convincing answer anywhere. Please help.

Comment: It strikes me as a bit of an overstatement, but they could be referring to the fact that they're strongly typed as opposed to `#define` declarations. Or it could be referred to the fact that if you have a `const` in C, you can easily do a cast that violates the `const` of the original declaration. Or it could be that Swift allows you to define more complicated value types (e.g. `struct`) that are constants. It's not clear to me from this one sentence as to precisely which aspect Apple was talking about. Personally, I might say "safer, strongly typed", not "much more powerful".

Comment: FWIW, I think that Apple has a tendency to talk about Swift in hyperbole. Have you ever read the `man` page for the `swift` command line program? It says little of substance about the actual syntax of the command (which is the point of `man` pages, IMHO), but rather reads like it was written by the marketing team.

Comment: Thanks Rob. so, it's all basically marketing campaign rather than technical stuff. I should start practicing to have this line of thought about Apple statements..:-)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go that far. It's not just a "marketing campaign". Swift offers very real advantages over C (and Objective-C). I, for one, would never want to go back to the dark days of large C projects. But, admittedly, Apple can get overly effusive at times.

Comment: @Rob "Or it could be referred to the fact that if you have  `const` in C, you can easily do a cast that violates the `const` of the original declaration." I don't know how you could categorize apple's claim as an over statement. That's a ***huge*** improvement. Another perk to add: Swift's constants can have their type inferred

Comment: @Alexander - I was just reacting to "much more powerful", which feels like marketing-speak. I would have left it at "safer" or "more robust".

Comment: @Rob Fair enough. Though when you take definitive initialization into account, I would definitely agree with them. They're worlds ahead

Comment: @Alexander C gives much more responsibility to programmer. Casting away constness is only safe in specific situations, otherwise it is undefined behavior, and it's programmers responsibility to not write broken code. The whole safety difference of these languages is huge of course, but this isn't really `const` specific thing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here are some of the advantages of Swift's constants (`let` properties), over those found in C:

- Type inference
- Actually guaranteed const-ness, in C you could just cast away the constness

  ```
  const SomeType constVar = someValue();
  mutatingFunction((SomeType) constVar); // Uh oh
  ```

  Swift forbids circumventing const correctness like this.
- More nuanced notions of scope; `let` properties can exist:

  - at a file level (the only place consts are allowed in C)
  - within an extension (`static` or `class` properties only), with the ability to give them `private` access. (which defines a new access protection boundary, C's access protection is limited to only file boundaries)
  - at a type level, as instance, `static`, or `class` properties. (C structs can't defnie `static` consts)
- Swift guarentees definitive initialization. All `let` properties are guarenteed to be assigned in an `init`. None are ever left dangling with undefined values.
- `let` properties can be declared as the targets of the destructing of a tuple, even with heterogeneous types.

  ```
  let (name, age) = ("Bob", "20") // Declares and assigns 2 different variables, at once
  ```

  C **does** support multiple assignments in one statement using the `,` operator, **but they must be of the same type**. E.g. `int x = 1, y = 2;`

Comment: Seems like these are general features of Swift, which is more powerful in many ways, and much safer than C in general. None are very const specific (well maybe 2, though you can't cast away constness and mutate an actual const *object*, that's undefined behavior).

Comment: @hyde What's UB, discouraged but not enforced in C, is strictly enforced by Swift. I chalk it up as something that makes Swift constant's "more powerful".

Comment: @hyde  And yes, these may seem "general" because they're such central features of Swift, but they're all highly relevant to constants in the language